# Leaflet calculating meters per pixel at zoom level

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geo

I am trying to determine a way to calculate the number of meters represented by 1 pixel at a given zoom level and geo centerpoint in Leaflet.  Could anyone direct me to the math involved or if there is a way to do this out of the box in leaflet? I am not finding much out there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [containerPointToLatLng](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-containerpointtolatlng) conversion function of `L.Map` to get the latLngcoordinates for a given pixelcoordinate. If you take one of the first pixel, and one of the next, you can use the [distanceTo](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto) utility method of `L.LatLng` to calculate the distance in meters between them. See the following code (assuming map is an instance of L.Map):

```
var centerLatLng = map.getCenter(); // get map center
var pointC = map.latLngToContainerPoint(centerLatLng); // convert to containerpoint (pixels)
var pointX = [pointC.x + 1, pointC.y]; // add one pixel to x
var pointY = [pointC.x, pointC.y + 1]; // add one pixel to y

// convert containerpoints to latlng's
var latLngC = map.containerPointToLatLng(pointC);
var latLngX = map.containerPointToLatLng(pointX);
var latLngY = map.containerPointToLatLng(pointY);

var distanceX = latLngC.distanceTo(latLngX); // calculate distance between c and x (latitude)
var distanceY = latLngC.distanceTo(latLngY); // calculate distance between c and y (longitude)
```

That should work, thanks to  Jarek Piórkowski for pointing my mistake before the edit.

Comment: "I'm not sure why you mentioned the centerpoint since the results will be the same all from whereever you take them." No they won't. Lengths of degrees of latitude and longitude vary by latitude, at large scales it can make a difference. You can test it out on e.g. http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html

Comment: ah ofcourse :) i knew that, somehow forgot about it. i'll edit my answer, thanks a lot

Comment: This works for me when zoomed out, but fails when zoomed in - `distanceX` is zero. Choosing a pixel 100px away, and then dividing the result by 100 seems to work better. I don't know if that is a valid approach or not.

Answer (score 12):

You can use this to work out the metres per pixel:

```
metresPerPixel = 40075016.686 * Math.abs(Math.cos(map.getCenter().lat * Math.PI/180)) / Math.pow(2, map.getZoom()+8);
```

Comment: Very interesting, could you expand a bit more? I'm curious where the 2^(zoom+8) comes from, and whether the "zoom level" number is independent from the projection used. I'm guessing the magic number is the length of the Earth's equator.

Comment: Just to confirm: the answer above appears to be correct, I have implemented the solution provided by iH8 and the one above by synkyo side-by-side and they return the same result to 6 decimal places. Source: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

Comment: couple more complementary explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703212/how-to-convert-radius-in-metres-to-pixels-in-mapbox-leaflet

Comment: I think that the above is meant to be `...Math.cos(map.getCenter().lat Math.PI/180))...` instead of `... Math.cos(map.getCenter().lat * 180/Math.PI))...` because we are converting from degrees to radians.

Comment: I am told by a Leaflet dev (Per Liedman) that this method will only work in EPSG:3857.

Comment: @mwakerman indeed, I didn't pay attention to your comment and got wrong results, so I edited the answer to fix it (I guess synkyo is not around anymore).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [openstreetmap.org page on zoom levels](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels). It gives this formula for calculating the meters per pixel:

> The distance represented by one pixel (S) is given by
>
> `S=C*cos(y)/2^(z+8)` where...
>
> C is the (equatorial) circumference of the Earth
>
> z is the zoom level
>
> y is the latitude of where you're interested in the scale.

Comment: I am told by a Leaflet dev (Per Liedman) that this method will only work in EPSG:3857.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I am wrong, IMHO, the number of meters per pixel = map height in meters / map height in pixels

```
function metresPerPixel() {
    const southEastPoint = map.getBounds().getSouthEast();
    const northEastPoint = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
    const mapHeightInMetres = southEastPoint.distanceTo(northEastPoint);
    const mapHeightInPixels = map.getSize().y;

    return mapHeightInMetres / mapHeightInPixels;
}
```