# Hide mapbox layer shapes that are too small

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

I have some geoJSON polygons that I render via layers on top of my map. Depending on the shape itself and the zoom level, sometimes the rendered shapes are too small and it doesn't make sense to even show them.

Is there a way to hide shapes that have rendered area less than some number?

Comment: Maybe you could calculate the size of the polygons and then decide if you want to render them or not. Turf.js might be helpful: 
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as [Babis.amas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4329077/babis-amas) suggested, first I calculate the area of the feature with help of `turf.area`. It gives the value in square meters. Then I convert this value to pixels using the function mentioned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30773300/2205002) And then it really depends on the shape type I'm dealing with. If the shape considered to be too small to be rendered, I just don't add it to the layer data feature collection.